# Pivot points in augmented matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I'm still learning about pivots in matrices. I've got this question that says

Suppose that the augmented matrix associated to a system of linear equations has a pivot in every column.

I had 4 answers to choose from on which was true and I believe that this means that since there is a pivot in every column then there is a unique solution to the system. Am I write on this? I'm practicing for an upcoming exam more or less on these 'find the true statement' types.

Answer (score 0):

No - there could be a pivot in the augmented column. Consider:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$